# Apply two ClearCase labels from a single cleartool find command

Tags: command-line, clearcase, cleartool

Is there a way to apply two ClearCase labels from a command line ( on Windows ) in a single cleartool find command running on a snapshot view ?
Meaning when running this simple command I want that 2 labels (REL3 and REL3_NEW) will be applied and not just REL3

```
  cmd-context find . –version 'version(\main\LATEST) && ! lbtype(REL3)' ^
  –exec 'cleartool mklabel –replace REL3 %CLEARCASE_XPN%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and concatenate the two mklabel:

```
cleartool find . –version 'version(\main\LATEST) && ! lbtype(REL3)' ^
 –exec 'cleartool mklabel –replace REL3 %CLEARCASE_XPN% && cleartool mklabel –replace REL2 %CLEARCASE_XPN%'
```

(The [`mklabel` command](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-41) supports only one label-type-selector, and multiple pnames)

Comment: This did not seem to work in a cygwin (actually MSys2) shell; of course there is the issue that cleartool probably invokes cmd for the `-exec` part and that there is another indirection involved.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider That is possible. I don't use cygwin, and Msys2 was barely a year old when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be working:

```
  cleartool find %1 -cview -version "{brtype(branch) && !version(.../(branch/0) && !version(.../(branch/CHECKEDOUT) && !lbtype(REL3)}" -exec "cleartool mklabel -replace REL3 \"%%CLEARCASE_XPN%%\"" -exec "cleartool mklabel -replace REL3_NEW \"%%CLEARCASE_XPN%%\""
```

Comment: This worked perfectly well for me in an Msys shell on Windows 10.